# Merge changes from specific file to its copy in same branch in Git

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

I need to merge changes on a specific file A in Git into another file A (which is a copy of A with changes afterwards) in the same branch. I'm new to git but I probably can't work with branches here.

I have two branches:

```
Branch "Manufacturer"
Branch "CustomDevelopment"
```

And the following files:

```
"Manufacturer" -> /files/A
"CustomDevelopment" -> /files/A
"CustomDevelopment" -> /files/extensions/override/A (copy of /files/A with modifications)
```

The application has a special concept where I can override `/file/A` by simply putting a file in `/files/extensions/override/A`. The application then uses file A from the override folder instead of `A` in `/file`.

Now when the manufacturer releases a new version, I update the Manufacturer branch and then merge the changes into CustomDevelopment branch. The problem now is: how can I get the changes that were done on `/files/A` with git to `/files/extensions/override/A`?

UPDATE: 
Files are HTML templates. Therefore its not possible to use a language specific concept for solving this without git. On "Manufacturer" I can't make custom changes/development and need to work with existing files.

Answer (score 0):

Configuration or behavioral overrides are best handled in the language itself via some inheritance or composition mechanism. "This is just like `/files/A` but with these differences ...". For instance, file inclusion followed by overriding definitions. If you don't have that, the next best thing is to generate the files with some textual (pre-)processing.

You really want to avoid constantly having to merge changes in `/files/A` to the the derived `/files/extensions/override/A`.

That said, you can get the changes to `/files/A` in patch form and just apply them with `patch` or `git apply`. Use the patch strip level to remove components. Something like:

```
files $ git diff <rev1> <rev2> -- A > ../A-patch.diff
files $ cd ../extensions/override
extensions/override $ git apply -p2 < ../../A-patch.diff
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems that I have to try your last suggestion (patch). Because the files are HTML files so I can't use something else.

Comment: Question: Does GIT patch/apply consider the fact, that override/A is a copy of files/A or is it a plain normal merge operation between two different files without knowing/using the same origin information?

Comment: @CubeSilence HTML files could be generated with text processing. The structure of the project source code doesn't have to be a mirror of what is deployed; the deployed structure can be generated by some build process.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your idea but the files are already templates which generate the webpage. So it doesnt work that way. If there is no option to achieve this properly with GIT - we have to do those merges manually as it seems.

Comment: @CubeSilence Templates can be generated by meta-templates. For instance PHP code generates webpages in server apps. You wouldn't want to copy and paste reams of similar PHP if you could generate it from one file with some macro processor like M4 or whatever.

Comment: Unfortunately if have no control about the work done in the "Manufacturer" branch. Therefore definitly no option.